# UINavigationController in UITabBarController not completely wraps UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an `UITabBarController` as my `rootViewcontroller` which has 3 `UINavigationController` for each Tab. Each `UINavigationController` has an initial `UIViewController` which just has a red background color.
My Problem is that the `UINavigationController` does not completely cover the `UIViewController` at the first start. After switching the tabs it covers the `UIViewController`. So what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

AppDelegate:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.rootViewController = TabBarViewController()
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

UITabBarController:

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Navigation Tab
        let navVC = NavigationViewController()

        // Departure Tab
        let depVC = DeparturesViewController()

        // Settings Tab
        let setVC = SettingsViewController()

        self.viewControllers = [
            createNavigationController(title: "Navigation", rootViewController: navVC, imageName: "map"),
            createNavigationController(title: "Abfahrten", rootViewController: depVC, imageName: "station"),
            createNavigationController(title: "Einstellungen", rootViewController: setVC, imageName: "user"),
        ]        
    }

    private func createNavigationController(title: String, rootViewController: UIViewController, imageName: String) -> UINavigationController {

        rootViewController.title = title
        let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        nc.title = title
        nc.view.backgroundColor = .white
        nc.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        nc.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        nc.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: imageName)?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
        return nc
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    }

}
```

The very simple UIViewController:

```
class NavigationViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please try to change nc.view.background to rootViewController.view.backgroundcolor

Comment: Same effect appears. Also if I set no backgroundcolor at all the same effect appears with an black color

Answer (score 0):

After removing following code form the TabBarController it completely wraps the Viewcontroller

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

But I can't explain why